# I have 2 Audacity windows: how can I use microphone 1 in window 1 and microphone 2 in window 2?

Tags: windows, audio, microphone, audacity

I have 2 Audacity windows: how can I use microphone 1 in window 1 and microphone 2 in window 2? Whenever I change the microphone in one window, it  changes the microphone and the other window.

[image]

I use Audacity 2.3.1 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Audacity has some documentation that may help.

Refer to this link: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/faq_recording_how_to_s.html

Comment: Thanks, if the subsection you're referring to is "Can I record from two microphones (or two audio interfaces) at the same time?", then it seems to address the different task: in my case I don't aim at recording from the microphone at the same time, but have one Audacity window records microphone 1 and another Audacity window records microphone 2, not necessarily recording simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Audacity doesn't support multiple running instances from the same user account. But you can run a different instance from a different user account with the "runas" command. It is slightly complex but works.

For example, create new user account named "user1" with non-empty password. Log in to this account once to allow the system to create user profile (you can use the "switch user" feature for that to avoid logging out from your favorite account). Log out from the new account, returning to your favorite account.

Each time you want to run a second Audacity instance, open the "Run" dialog (Win-R) and type:

runas /user:user1 audacity-path

substituting full EXE path in double quotes. All settings that you change in this instance, will be kept separately.

To use three independent instances, create a second user account, and so on.